# excel - custom function not working with filtering

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have this:

[image]

I have VBA code:

```
Public Function CONCATENATESPECIAL(rng As Range) As String

Dim rng1 As Range

CONCATENATESPECIAL = ""

   For Each rng1 In rng
        If rng1.Value <> "" Then
        CONCATENATESPECIAL = CONCATENATESPECIAL & rng1.Text & " | "
        End If
   Next rng1

End Function
```

I need to go through column and write down content in it separated by "|", which is working perfectly.

My issue is that it doesnt work with filtering. When I filter out something, its still displaying the same results.

[after filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q67mv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your criteria:

`If (not rng1.EntireRow.Hidden) And (rng1.Value <> "") Then`

Comment: Awesome guys! `If (Not Rows(rng1.Row).Hidden) And (rng1.Value <> "") Then` solved it! Thank you very much!